# Split long image into DOC/PDF with 2 slices per page?

Tags: pdf, images, documents

I have a rather unusual situation. I have to make printable documents from very large images that are essentially printscreens. They are ~40000px in height and around 600px in width. (I'll try to illustrate what I'm trying to do). So let's say this is an image I have:

[image: screenshot]

I want to split the image into equal segments:

[image: screenshot]

And then assemble the slices into pairs per page into some document like this:

[image: screenshot]

I've tried using [PosteRazor](http://posterazor.sourceforge.net/) to split an image into PDF pages, and it did the job, however it when trying to convert the PDF so that it has 2 pages in 1, I got something like this:

[image: screenshot]

The pages where shrunk down to keep the aspect ratio and the text was too small to read.

So my main goal, is to slice the images so that they would fit into half of a page and assemble them into a document with 2 images per page.

I could do the slicing part by hand in Photoshop with a custom action that I'd have to create once so not that big of a deal, but assembling ~40+ pages for multiple images and with possibly more in the future - I need to find some automated solution.

Hopefully someone has ideas I could try out.. Thanks guys!

Comment: Naive solution would be to set initial page size in PosteRazor to be half width of a normal page but with the same height; putting to pages on one standard page wouldn't require resizing.

Answer (score 0):

This is an idea I have from a software I frequently use. Dysprosium software is downloadable [here](http://messiahpsychoanalyst.org/Documents/Downloads.html).

You need to use two software they put there. One Dysprosium (Dolce Edition 2015) converts your slices into PDF files and the second one, Dysprosium Imposition, imposes PDF's in two-in-one.

Correspondence is one to one hence, two A5 becomes one A4. If you like then you can use one feature of the software to resize the PDf; say, from A3 to A4 with no loss of embedded information. You also might be able to use the hand-out feature of the first one.

They are free open software. You need to have Java already installed on your machine. Therefore, they are good for Windows, Mac, Unix. They are portable and won't install anything or alter your machine.

[image]